# angular save/serialize $scope state

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I had built a very complex controller with a lot of models and watchers.
I want to be able to save the current state of the Controller model, so the user will be able to click "save to draft".

I thought about serializing the whole $scope object but it appears to be [impossible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17522049/angularjs-viewmodel-serialization).

Do you have any elegant solution to this problem?

Comment: Why is it "impossible"? Totally possible.

Comment: What's the problem? How about putting that data in an object: `$scope.somethingToSerialize = {...}`

Comment: you should just serialize the data - not the whole `$scope`

Comment: the problem is that I already have numerous of models in this $scope, so refactoring the Controller to have all the models attached to a single point which I will be able to serialize is a nightmare.

Comment: http://img.memecdn.com/if-nothing-is-impossible_o_1833271.jpg

Comment: @dfsq how can you do it?

Comment: This is how I "serialize" $scope:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put all your models in a single `$scope` field e.g. `state`.

```
$scope.state = {model1: 'value 1', model2: 'value 2'};
```

Then you can store the complete controller state storing this single field only.

Answer (score 2):

An elegant answer would probably to try to serialize the data you're trying to retain from the $scope, and reapply it whenever you need it (saving it to server/cookies/localstorage).

Why try to keep the whole scope object, rather than just the data you need?

I might not grasp completely your question, though.

Furthermore, if you're using a stame machine such as angular-ui-router, you can keep the current page state.

Comment: I am having a lot of models attached to the $scope, I am looking for elegant solution not copying them one by one...
buy thanks anyway!

Comment: Plus angular extends the `$scope` object with things that allow it to keep track of its state etc, you don't want to be copying and applying them either, you could end up short-circuiting things so to speak. such as `$parent, $$childHead, $$listeners, $id, $$watchers`

Answer (score 1):

You should not use the `$scope` to store all your data into. Use services and providers for that. By doing so, you can use the services you created on different controllers without having to rewrite code. All your logic should be in those services not in the controllers. Service are singleton it is shared across your controllers. Only use $scope for exposing models into your html, if you don't need the data in your templates, don't put it there. If you put too much data in the $scope, your app will run slower because it will be added to $watch

Answer (score 0):

This is how I keep a copy of the `$scope`'s state (uses lodash):

```
function copyScope(scope) {
    return _.pick(scope, function (index, key) {
        return typeof (scope[key]) !== 'function' && key.charAt(0) !== '$';
    });
}
```

In my controller, I monitor changes in `$scope`'s state:

```
$scope.$watch(function watchScope() {
    return copyScope($scope);
}, function saveScope(scopeCopy) {
    // stateManager stores it as JSON in local storage
    stateManager.set(stateKey, scopeCopy);
}, true);
```

To load the state, you simply take the deserialized JSON and put it on your scope:

```
angular.extend($scope, JSON.parse(scopeCopyJson));
```